# Problem reading a formatted text file in C++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream, getline

Officially my first post. I'm sure the Stack is full of answers, but the problem that I need help with is a little bit specific. So here goes nothing...

## The Task:

I'm doing a small school project and in one part of my program I need to read the temperature measurements at different locations, all from a single formatted text file. The data inside the file is written as follows:

> ```
> 23/5/2016  
> Location 1  
> -7,12,-16,20,18,13,6  
> 9/11/2014  
> Location 2  
> −1,3,6,10,8  
> 9/11/2014  
> Location 3  
> −5,−2,0,3,1,2,−1,−4
> ```

The first row represents the date, second row the location and the third row represents the all the measurements the were taken on that day (degrees Celsius).
The code that I wrote for this part of the program looks something like this:

```
tok.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
int i = 0;
double element;
char sign = ',';
while (!tok.eof()) {
  vector_measurements.resize(vector_measurements.size() + 1);
  tok >> vector_measurements.at(i).day >> sign >> vector_measurements.at(i).month >> sign >> vector_measurements.at(i).year >> std::ws;
  std::getline(tok, vector_measurements.at(i).location);
  sign = ',';
  while (tok && sign == ',') {
    tok >> element;
    vector_measurements.at(i).measurements.push_back(element);
    sign = tok.get();
  }
  if (!tok.eof() && !tok) {
    tok.clear();
    break;
  }
  vector_measurements.at(i).SetAverage();
  i++;
}
```

The code that I'm presenting is linked to a class:

```
struct Data {
  std::string location;
  std::vector<int> measurements;
  int day, month, year;
  double average = 0;

  void SetAverage();
  int GetMinimalTemperature();
  int GetMaximalTemperature();
};
```

I've already checked and confirmed that the file exists and the stream is opened in the correct mode without any errors; all class methods working as intended. But here's the problem. Later on, after the data is sorted (the part of data that has been successfully read), it fails to correctly print the data on the screen. I get something like:

```
Location 2
Date: 9/11/2014
Minimal temperature: 0
Maximal temperature: 0
Average temperature: 0

Location 1
Date: 23/5/2016
Minimal temperature: -16
Maximal temperature: 20
Average temperature: 6.57143
```

; but I expect:

```
Location 3
----------
Date: 9/11/2014
Minimal temperature: -5
Maximal temperature: 3
Average temperature: -0.75

Location 2
----------
Date: 9/11/2014
Minimal temperature: -1
Maximal temperature: 10
Average temperature: 5.20

Location 1
----------
Date: 23/5/2016
Minimal temperature: -16
Maximal temperature: 20
Average temperature: 6.57143
```

## The Problem:

The order of the locations is good, since I'm sorting from the lowest to the highest average temperature. But no matter the number of locations, the first location is always correct, the second one only has zero's, and every other location isn't even printed on the screen.
What do I need to change in order for my program to read the data properly? Or am I just missing something? Forgive me for any spelling mistakes I made since English isn't my native language. Thank you all in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to use `vector.at()` instead of just `myVector[index]`? Just cuyrious.

Comment: If we don't use the at() function, we get 0 points on the assignment even if it's fully functional and correct. It's the professor's way of encouraging us to pay attention to out of bounds access; since at() checks if the range is valid.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is there is some garbage in your text file. I do believe these are `\0` characters, but I am not sure. They present themselves as `?` characters in Atom text editor.

You're quite lucky StackOverflow didn't sanitize them, otherwise, nobody would be able to help you.

After I cleaned up the text file, your code works. You just need to also kill the loop and drop the last item when the file ends, I did it like this. It's not optimal but it works.

```
  while (!tok.eof())
  {
    vector_measurements.resize(vector_measurements.size() + 1);
    Data& currentItem = vector_measurements[i];
    tok >> currentItem.day >> sign >> currentItem.month >> sign >> currentItem.year >> std::ws;

    // If the file ends, the data is invalid and the last item can be thrown away
    if (tok.eof())
    {
      vector_measurements.pop_back();
      break;
    }

    std::getline(tok, currentItem.location);
    sign = ',';
    while (tok && sign == ',')
    {
      tok >> element;
      currentItem.measurements.push_back(element);
      sign = tok.get();
    }
    if (!tok.eof() && !tok)
    {
      tok.clear();
      break;
    }
    currentItem.SetAverage();
    i++;
  }
```

Please inspect your file with hex editor and observe the weird characters, then figure out how to get rid of them.

Comment: I think that the weird characters are there because we edit the file ourselves. We input the text in the notepad, as told, save the file with an .DAT extension, and then we open it inside the program. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: @Empirius There is no way for me to know how did you manage to put these characters in the file. You will need to investigate that yourself. Or just write a simple script to clean up the file before loading it. I answered what I could based on the information in your question.

Comment: Cleaning up the file should be the best thing to do. I'm so glad that we figured this out. Thank you so much for all the help!